# How do I throttle how frequently lines of output are passed on?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

## Wish

I want to run a command repeatedly in response to lines piped to it:

```sh
firehose | expensive-command
```

However, I'm getting a lot of lines, and the command is resource-intensive.  I want the input for the command to be filtered, such that it only runs at most once every *x* seconds:

```sh
firehose | interval 1 second | expensive-command
```

The `interval` command should not just be a filter.  It should send the most recently received line at the end of its cooldown period if it has one, rather than just block everything arriving during the cooldown.

How can I do this?

---

## Attempt

```sh
epoch () { date +%s --date="$*" }

interval () {
    INTERVAL="$*"
    LAST_RUN_AT=0
    WHEN_TO_RUN=0
    while read LINE; do
        if (( $(epoch now) >= $WHEN_TO_RUN )) then
            echo $LINE
            WHEN_TO_RUN="$(epoch now + $INTERVAL)"
        fi
    done
}

alias firehose='(print "1\n2\n3" ; sleep 2 ; print "4\n")'
alias expensive-command='cat'

firehose | interval 1 second | expensive-command
```

That mostly works, but has the problem that it can't delay passing lines on until later—it can only decide to pass them on immediately, or drop them.

#### What happens:

```
1
4
```

The throttle receives the `1`, and passes it on, then goes on cooldown.  The `1` and `3` arrive during the cooldown, so they are discarded completely.  The cooldown finishes before `4` arrives, so it is passed on.

[image: what-happens diagram]

#### What I wished would happen:

```
1
3
4
```

After receiving the `1`, the throttle should go on cooldown for 1 second.  Then it should receive the `2`, and file it for later because it's still on cooldown.  Then it receives the `3`, which replaces the `2` filed for later.  The throttle then comes off cooldown, at which point it should immediately send `3`.  Finally, the `4` arrives as that round is back off cooldown, so it is sent immediately.

[image: what-i-wish-would-happen diagram]

If zsh had [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), I'd launch a subshell that sleeps for `$INTERVAL`, then `echo`es the last received `LINE`, but alas, zsh has no closures.

Comment: If you know how to solve it with closures, why not just write `interval` in a language that supports closures? You did not mention why or even if you need a pure `zsh` solution.

Comment: @Adaephon There are definitely saner languages for this, but I figured I could learn something from trying to use zsh, even if the main lesson is "don't use zsh for this". :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want closures for.

Comment: @Gilles I was thinking the `$LINE` variable could be shared between the main process and a backgrounded subshell. The backgrounded one would loop over `sleep $INTERVAL; echo $LINE`, and the main one would just read new values into to `$LINE` continuously. Then the most recent one would always be echoed by the subshell, at the correct interval.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent UDP packets.

Comment: See my answer update (first variant added). Does it do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

Here's my `interval` script (also [on github](https://github.com/anko/zthrottle)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# Lets a line pass only once every $1 seconds.  If multiple lines arrive during
# the cooldown interval, only the latest is passed on when the cooldown ends.

INTERVAL="$1"

CHILD_PID=
BUFFER=$(mktemp)
CAN_PRINT_IMMEDIATELY=1
CAN_START_SUBPROCESS=1

# Reset state when child process returns
child-return () {
    CAN_START_SUBPROCESS=1
    CAN_PRINT_IMMEDIATELY=1
}
trap child-return CHLD

# Clean up when quitting
cleanup () {
    kill -TERM "$CHILD_PID" &> /dev/null
    rm "$BUFFER"
    exit
}
trap cleanup TERM INT QUIT

while read LINE; do
    # If we're just starting, just print immediately
    if [[ -n $CAN_PRINT_IMMEDIATELY ]]; then
        echo $LINE
        CAN_PRINT_IMMEDIATELY=
    else
        # Otherwise, store the line for later
        echo "$LINE" > $BUFFER
        # And spawn a subprocess to handle it one interval later, unless one is
        # already running.  With the SIGCHLD trap, the state variables will
        # reset when it exits.
        if [[ -n $CAN_START_SUBPROCESS ]]; then
            CAN_START_SUBPROCESS=
            (
                sleep $INTERVAL
                tail -n1 $BUFFER
            ) &
            CHILD_PID=$!
        fi
    fi
done

# Once we exhaust stdin, wait for the last child process to finish, if any.
if [[ -n $CHILD_PID ]]; then
    wait $CHILD_PID &> /dev/null
    cleanup
fi
```

I observed that the loop `read`ing lines cannot always be in charge of printing them, because the program sometimes needs to print lines asynchronously (when none are being received, sometimes even long after `stdin` has ended).  Hence the child process.

Here's it working, with the input also `tee >(sed)`'d aside to observe the timing:

[image: GIF recording demonstrating that the script works on the example input given in the question]

That matches my earlier diagram:

[image: the wished-for result diagram from the question]

Answer (score 1):

#### First variant (not working, see second variant)

It seems, that we can’t use `read` command for this kind of tasks, because `read` stops `while` loop execution.

Look at this example: `(printf "1\n2\n3\n" ; sleep 5; printf "4\n") | while read -r line; do echo hello; done`.

`while` loop with `read` inside will executed such way:

- 1 iteration - read `1`;
- 2 iteration - read `2`;
- 3 iteration - read `3`;
- 4 iteration - WAITING 5 sec, then read `4`.

We can’t make scheduled work inside this loop, like “do this every 1 second” - because it will be stopped periodically, awaiting input. It may be awaiting for a 1 minute or more, for example, and our scheduled work will be stopped too.

```
function interval () {
    amount_of_seconds=$1
    print_time=0
    buffer=''
    while read -r line; do
        current_time=$(date +%s)

        if (( current_time > print_time )); then
            echo -e "${buffer}${line}"
            buffer=''
            print_time=$((current_time + amount_of_seconds))
        else
            buffer="$line\n"
        fi
    done
    echo -en "$buffer"
}
```

**Testing:**

```
$ alias firehose='(printf "1\n2\n3\n" ; sleep 2 ; printf "4\n"; sleep 2 ; printf "5\n6\n7\n" ; sleep 2; printf "8\n")'
$ firehose | interval 1 | cat
1
3
4
5
7
8
$
```

#### Second variant

Redirect the `firehose` output to the file:
`firehose >> buffer_file.txt` (Explanation why `>>` and not `>` see below)

`expensive-command` will be read the last line from this file every second and flush the file:

```
while true; do
    tail -n 1 buffer_file.txt | expensive-command
    # clear file
    echo -n '' > buffer_file.txt
    # and sleep 1 second
    sleep 1      
done
```

At the result, we will have next:

1. both command running simultaneously (`firehose` in the background):
   `firehose >> buffer_file.txt & ./script_with_expensive_command_inside.sh`
   APPEND operator - `>>` is needed after `firehose`, not WRITE `>`. Otherwise the file will not be cleaned and will grow continuously. [Here explanation this behaviour.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8518219/2913477)
2. All unwanted lines will dropped, only last will passed to the `expensive command`
3. The last line will be saved, before `expensive command` does not read it and clear file.

Comment: The first variant is close, but not quite. When I give it `print '1\n2\n3\n'` as input, it outputs only the `1` when it should give `1` and `3`.

Comment: @Anko Changes added. Now this case also processed.

Comment: That works otherwise, except the timing is wrong. There is no pause between the `3` and `4`.

Comment: The `expensive-command` must only receive a line every interval. If multiple lines could have been given to it during that interval, it should only get the last one when it cools down again; the other lines don't matter.

Comment: @Anko See answer update, it is not solution, but interesting :)

Comment: I finally came up with [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378672/16404) with a similar approach as your second variant. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **you need a read with a timeout**.  If `firehose` isn't sending anything, your loop **blocks indefinitely**, and when it's doing that, it fails to send the line that had been most recently received. **Bash has the -t argument for a timed-out read.** If zsh's `read` has this, that would be the thing to use.

The algorithm is to keep reading lines with a timeout that is always re-calculated (shortened more and more) to expire at the end of the one second (or whatever) interval. When that interval arrives, then if one or more lines had been read, send the last one. Otherwise send nothing and now start reading lines for the next interval.

You can implement an "instant pass" for the very first line that is received, or for the first line which is received after a period of time longer than the interval. Like if the interval is 1 second, and nothing has come from `firehose` for 1.5 since the last time a line was output, then that line can be passed through, and the machinery can reset to start a new one second interval at that point.

This proof-of-concept implementation in TXR Lisp works for me, validating the basic algorithm:

```
(defvarl %interval% 1000000) ;; us

(defun epoch-usec ()
  (tree-bind (sec . usec) (time-usec)
    (+ (* 1000000 sec) usec)))

(let ((now (epoch-usec))
      (*stdin* (open-fileno (fileno *stdin*) "rl")) ;; line buffered
      remaining-time next-time line done)
  (while (not done)
    (set next-time (+ now %interval%))
    (set remaining-time (- next-time now))
    (while (poll (list (cons *stdin* poll-in))
                 (trunc remaining-time 1000))
      ;; got a line or EOF poll: no timeout
      (iflet ((nline (get-line)))
        (set line nline)              ;; got line
        (progn (flip done) (return))) ;; EOF poll
      (set now (epoch-usec))
      (when (minusp (set remaining-time (- next-time now)))
        (return)))
    ;; timeout, past deadline or exit: flush line, if any:
    (when line
      (put-line line)
      (set line nil))))
```

An unbuffered stream is set up, because `poll` is being used for the timed-out reads, and `poll` doesn't see stream buffers. The idea is that we don't want to be polling for input, while there is unread buffered data in the stream. This is a nitpick. In testing, I didn't really see any qualitative difference in behavior between this and just using the buffered, original `*stdin*` stream. If we waste time polling when there is buffered data in the stream and none in the file descriptor, we are guaranteed not to wait longer than our interval time, and less than that if new data arrives sooner.

We are assuming that a successful `poll` means that we can read a full line. `poll` doesn't guarantee that, of course, but a well-behaved text stream input sources should provide the guarantee that if one byte of input is available to wake up `poll`, there is a full line following that byte without any undue delay.

The remaining time calculations use calendar time, while `poll` just uses a relative wait that is probably insensitive to time adjustments. So the usual caveats apply. If the clock suddenly jumps backwards, oops!

These test cases proceed without any noticeable delay:

```
$ echo foo | txr throttle.txr
foo
$ (echo foo; echo bar) | txr throttle.tl 
bar
$ (echo foo; echo bar; echo xyzzy) | txr throttle.tl 
xyzzy
```

Then:

```
$ (echo foo; sleep 2; echo bar; sleep 2; echo xyzzy) | txr throttle.tl 
foo
bar
xyzzy
```

I've tested with `find / | txr throttle.tl` and such.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want in a very shellish way :)

```
firehose | awk '{print $1; system("sleep 1")}' | expensive-command
```

It has the drawback that the whole thing becomes somewhat hard to kill (`killall awk` works but is moderately elegant) but at least it's simple and requires no special script or anything.

Comment: No, this isn't what is desired. You're outputting each line in order. But the question asks how to send *the most recent line* each time, i.e. discard lines received during the sleep period except for the last one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the explanation of Anko's question. Well then I'd actually concur with Adaephon tbh: if you can't have something that fits in the pipe anyway, use a proper language for this or change the question to something like "How do I filter input lines based on a clock tick _in zsh_?" I also can't imagine that it's hard to do, even if you insist on using zsh as a language: save every line that comes through in a global variable and send USR1 to the script once per second. Then output the global variable in the event handler.